# how wchar_t data type working c?

Tags: c++, c, user-defined-types

I know it is not a built in data type. In c++ i understand we can create a data type which looks and acts almost similar to basic data type. But in C I don't understand how it works similar to basic data type.

Comment: C11 standardizes unicode support. With it, the `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t` types were introduced, along with `uchar.h` header... [check this resume of the latest standard](http://blog.smartbear.com/codereviewer/c11-a-new-c-standard-aiming-at-safer-programming/)

Comment: I mean to say it is not built in data type of C

Comment: That's where you're wrong, that's what everybody is telling you: since C11, it's part of the standard. It is a standard, built in, scalar data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I know it is not a standard data type
```

Yes, its standard (described in `<stddef.h>`)

> wchar_t
>       Integral type whose range of values can represent distinct wide-character codes for all members of the largest character set
>   specified among the locales supported by the compilation environment:
>   the null character has the code value 0 and each member of the
>   Portable Character Set has a code value equal to its value when used
>   as the lone character in an integer character constant.

```
But in C I don't understand how it works similar to basic data type.
```

Use the functions and macros of [wchar.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/wchar.h.html) header

Answer (score 0):

Both the C++11 and the C11 standards recognize `wchar_t` as a "wide character" standard data type.

The C11 standard defines the semantics of `wchar_t` in 7.19/2:

> The types are [...] and
>   `wchar_t`
>   which is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales; the null character shall have the code value zero. Each member of the basic character set
>   shall have a code value equal to its value when used as the lone character in an integer
>   character constant if an implementation does not define
>   `__STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__`.

While the C++11 standard says in 3.9.1/5:

> Type `wchar_t` is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest
>   extended character set specified among the supported locales (22.3.1). Type `wchar_t` shall have the same
>   size, signedness, and alignment requirements (3.11) as one of the other integral types, called its underlying
>   type. [...]

Answer (score 0):

In C, `wchar_t` is a typedef for an integer type defined in `<stddef.h>` (and possibly other headers).

See the Standard, section 7.17 ( http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.17 )

> `wchar_t` is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales; the null character shall have the code value zero.